# How can I show the last update time on my wiki's home page

Tags: mediawiki, last-modified

I want to show something like: "This wiki was last updated on: dd/mm/yy at mm:ss", or maybe a fuzzy date like: "This wiki was last updated: 3 hours ago"

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: There is a News extension for this purpose: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:News is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Are you looking for one time stamp for the whole wiki? Or for each page?